# Avahi service file for mDNS option for Physical Web

Tags: mdns, avahi

Physical Web docs vague about mDNS advertising. I am using Avahi to advertise a global app via mDNS and tried many combinations of service file parameters:

```
<?xml version="1.0" standalone='no'?>
<!DOCTYPE service-group SYSTEM "avahi-service.dtd">
<service-group>
  <name>name-of-service</name>
  <service protocol="ipv4">
    <host-name>host.name.com</host-name>
    <type>_https._tcp</type>
    <port>443</port>
  </service>
 </service-group>
```

Is there a concrete definition of the form of the mDNS advertisement for physical web?

Comment: It's not clear exactly what you mean by "Physical Web".  Can you elaborate?

Comment: https://google.github.io/physical-web/  - For this question it refers to utilizing mDNS for an advertisement. Typically physical web is about BLE beacons. Interacting with the physical world thru your phone. In its simplest form a BLE beacon advertises a URL - so the phone get notified and the user load a web app to iteract with the device having the beacon.